# ssh only login not working on debian 12

Tags: debian, ssh

**Problem stems from Debian auto configuring ssh on installation.
Proper solution besides nuking the install has yet to be found**

So I have followed this [tutorial](https://www.debian.org/devel/passwordlessssh) on how to set up ssh key login but no matter what I do it will never ever allow for me to login without a pass word I have been trying all day to get this to work and honestly I'm tired of it just going to dump the ssh -vvv as well as my server sshd_config

```
OpenSSH_9.2p1 Debian-2, OpenSSL 3.0.9 30 May 2023
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: include /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/*.conf matched no files
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 21: Applying options for *
debug2: resolve_canonicalize: hostname 72.230.162.46 is address
debug3: expanded UserKnownHostsFile '~/.ssh/known_hosts' -> '/home/blaine/.ssh/known_hosts'
debug3: expanded UserKnownHostsFile '~/.ssh/known_hosts2' -> '/home/blaine/.ssh/known_hosts2'
debug3: ssh_connect_direct: entering
debug1: Connecting to 72.230.162.46 [72.230.162.46] port 10580.
debug3: set_sock_tos: set socket 3 IP_TOS 0x10
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/blaine/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/blaine/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/blaine/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/blaine/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/blaine/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk type -1
debug1: identity file /home/blaine/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/blaine/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: identity file /home/blaine/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/blaine/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk type -1
debug1: identity file /home/blaine/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/blaine/.ssh/id_xmss type -1
debug1: identity file /home/blaine/.ssh/id_xmss-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/blaine/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/blaine/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_9.2p1 Debian-2
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_9.2p1 Debian-2
debug1: compat_banner: match: OpenSSH_9.2p1 Debian-2 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug1: Authenticating to 72.230.162.46:10580 as 'blaine'
debug3: put_host_port: [72.230.162.46]:10580
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type ED25519 in file /home/blaine/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type RSA in file /home/blaine/.ssh/known_hosts:2
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type ECDSA in file /home/blaine/.ssh/known_hosts:3
debug3: load_hostkeys_file: loaded 3 keys from [72.230.162.46]:10580
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /home/blaine/.ssh/known_hosts2: No such file or directory
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts: No such file or directory
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts2: No such file or directory
debug3: order_hostkeyalgs: have matching best-preference key type ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com, using HostkeyAlgorithms verbatim
debug3: send packet: type 20
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug3: receive packet: type 20
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug2: local client KEXINIT proposal
debug2: KEX algorithms: sntrup761x25519-sha512@openssh.com,curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256,ext-info-c
debug2: host key algorithms: ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,sk-ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-512-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-ed25519,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,sk-ssh-ed25519@openssh.com,sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256
debug2: ciphers ctos: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: ciphers stoc: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: MACs ctos: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: MACs stoc: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: languages ctos: 
debug2: languages stoc: 
debug2: first_kex_follows 0 
debug2: reserved 0 
debug2: peer server KEXINIT proposal
debug2: KEX algorithms: sntrup761x25519-sha512@openssh.com,curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256
debug2: host key algorithms: rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ssh-ed25519
debug2: ciphers ctos: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: ciphers stoc: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: MACs ctos: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: MACs stoc: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: languages ctos: 
debug2: languages stoc: 
debug2: first_kex_follows 0 
debug2: reserved 0 
debug1: kex: algorithm: sntrup761x25519-sha512@openssh.com
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ssh-ed25519
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug3: send packet: type 30
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug3: receive packet: type 31
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY received
debug1: Server host key: ssh-ed25519 SHA256:JvAJjOp0E5K3E0osjrt3okUe1VEKtS2HUVoRhZVd3H0
debug3: put_host_port: [72.230.162.46]:10580
debug3: put_host_port: [72.230.162.46]:10580
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type ED25519 in file /home/blaine/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type RSA in file /home/blaine/.ssh/known_hosts:2
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type ECDSA in file /home/blaine/.ssh/known_hosts:3
debug3: load_hostkeys_file: loaded 3 keys from [72.230.162.46]:10580
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /home/blaine/.ssh/known_hosts2: No such file or directory
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts: No such file or directory
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts2: No such file or directory
debug1: Host '[72.230.162.46]:10580' is known and matches the ED25519 host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/blaine/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug3: send packet: type 21
debug2: ssh_set_newkeys: mode 1
debug1: rekey out after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug3: receive packet: type 21
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug2: ssh_set_newkeys: mode 0
debug1: rekey in after 134217728 blocks
debug3: ssh_get_authentication_socket_path: path '/tmp/ssh-XXXXXXN08dgn/agent.1232'
debug1: get_agent_identities: bound agent to hostkey
debug1: get_agent_identities: ssh_fetch_identitylist: agent contains no identities
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/blaine/.ssh/id_rsa 
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/blaine/.ssh/id_ecdsa 
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/blaine/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk 
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/blaine/.ssh/id_ed25519 
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/blaine/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk 
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/blaine/.ssh/id_xmss 
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/blaine/.ssh/id_dsa 
debug2: pubkey_prepare: done
debug3: send packet: type 5
debug3: receive packet: type 7
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<ssh-ed25519,sk-ssh-ed25519@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256@openssh.com,webauthn-sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256@openssh.com,ssh-dss,ssh-rsa,rsa-sha2-256,rsa-sha2-512>
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: publickey-hostbound@openssh.com=<0>
debug3: receive packet: type 6
debug2: service_accept: ssh-userauth
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug3: receive packet: type 51
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug3: start over, passed a different list publickey,password
debug3: preferred gssapi-with-mic,publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_lookup publickey
debug3: remaining preferred: keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /home/blaine/.ssh/id_rsa
debug3: no such identity: /home/blaine/.ssh/id_rsa: No such file or directory
debug1: Trying private key: /home/blaine/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug3: no such identity: /home/blaine/.ssh/id_ecdsa: No such file or directory
debug1: Trying private key: /home/blaine/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk
debug3: no such identity: /home/blaine/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk: No such file or directory
debug1: Trying private key: /home/blaine/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug3: no such identity: /home/blaine/.ssh/id_ed25519: No such file or directory
debug1: Trying private key: /home/blaine/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk
debug3: no such identity: /home/blaine/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk: No such file or directory
debug1: Trying private key: /home/blaine/.ssh/id_xmss
debug3: no such identity: /home/blaine/.ssh/id_xmss: No such file or directory
debug1: Trying private key: /home/blaine/.ssh/id_dsa
debug3: no such identity: /home/blaine/.ssh/id_dsa: No such file or directory
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug3: authmethod_lookup password
debug3: remaining preferred: ,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled password
debug1: Next authentication method: password
blaine@72.230.162.46's password: 
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug2: we sent a password packet, wait for reply
debug3: receive packet: type 52
Authenticated to 72.230.162.46 ([72.230.162.46]:10580) using "password".
debug1: channel 0: new session [client-session] (inactive timeout: 0)
debug3: ssh_session2_open: channel_new: 0
debug2: channel 0: send open
debug3: send packet: type 90
debug1: Requesting no-more-sessions@openssh.com
debug3: send packet: type 80
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: pledge: filesystem
debug3: client_repledge: enter
debug3: receive packet: type 80
debug1: client_input_global_request: rtype hostkeys-00@openssh.com want_reply 0
debug3: client_input_hostkeys: received RSA key SHA256:fpbyouqx+HhMcONsxnm3wDjaLwlw1jDUXCifGmG3Ohc
debug3: client_input_hostkeys: received ECDSA key SHA256:rxTk95GOVGISyEpy07jOknRry9Qw8xnn0oQjSm8WXKs
debug3: client_input_hostkeys: received ED25519 key SHA256:JvAJjOp0E5K3E0osjrt3okUe1VEKtS2HUVoRhZVd3H0
debug3: put_host_port: [72.230.162.46]:10580
debug1: client_input_hostkeys: searching /home/blaine/.ssh/known_hosts for [72.230.162.46]:10580 / (none)
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "/home/blaine/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: hostkeys_find: found ssh-ed25519 key at /home/blaine/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug3: hostkeys_find: found ssh-rsa key at /home/blaine/.ssh/known_hosts:2
debug3: hostkeys_find: found ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 key at /home/blaine/.ssh/known_hosts:3
debug1: client_input_hostkeys: searching /home/blaine/.ssh/known_hosts2 for [72.230.162.46]:10580 / (none)
debug1: client_input_hostkeys: hostkeys file /home/blaine/.ssh/known_hosts2 does not exist
debug3: client_input_hostkeys: 3 server keys: 0 new, 3 retained, 0 incomplete match. 0 to remove
debug1: client_input_hostkeys: no new or deprecated keys from server
debug3: client_repledge: enter
debug3: receive packet: type 91
debug2: channel_input_open_confirmation: channel 0: callback start
debug2: fd 3 setting TCP_NODELAY
debug3: set_sock_tos: set socket 3 IP_TOS 0x10
debug2: client_session2_setup: id 0
debug2: channel 0: request pty-req confirm 1
debug3: send packet: type 98
debug1: Sending environment.
debug3: Ignored env SHELL
debug3: Ignored env SESSION_MANAGER
debug3: Ignored env WINDOWID
debug3: Ignored env QT_ACCESSIBILITY
debug3: Ignored env COLORTERM
debug3: Ignored env XDG_CONFIG_DIRS
debug3: Ignored env XDG_SESSION_PATH
debug3: Ignored env XDG_MENU_PREFIX
debug3: Ignored env SSH_AUTH_SOCK
debug3: Ignored env DESKTOP_SESSION
debug3: Ignored env SSH_AGENT_PID
debug3: Ignored env GTK_MODULES
debug3: Ignored env XDG_SEAT
debug3: Ignored env PWD
debug3: Ignored env LOGNAME
debug3: Ignored env XDG_SESSION_DESKTOP
debug3: Ignored env XDG_SESSION_TYPE
debug3: Ignored env XAUTHORITY
debug3: Ignored env XDG_GREETER_DATA_DIR
debug3: Ignored env HOME
debug1: channel 0: setting env LANG = "en_US.UTF-8"
debug2: channel 0: request env confirm 0
debug3: send packet: type 98
debug3: Ignored env LS_COLORS
debug3: Ignored env XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP
debug3: Ignored env VTE_VERSION
debug3: Ignored env XDG_SEAT_PATH
debug3: Ignored env XDG_SESSION_CLASS
debug3: Ignored env TERM
debug3: Ignored env USER
debug3: Ignored env DISPLAY
debug3: Ignored env SHLVL
debug3: Ignored env XDG_VTNR
debug3: Ignored env XDG_SESSION_ID
debug3: Ignored env XDG_RUNTIME_DIR
debug3: Ignored env XDG_DATA_DIRS
debug3: Ignored env PATH
debug3: Ignored env GDMSESSION
debug3: Ignored env DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS
debug3: Ignored env OLDPWD
debug3: Ignored env _
debug2: channel 0: request shell confirm 1
debug3: send packet: type 98
debug3: client_repledge: enter
debug1: pledge: fork
debug2: channel_input_open_confirmation: channel 0: callback done
debug2: channel 0: open confirm rwindow 0 rmax 32768
debug3: receive packet: type 99
debug2: channel_input_status_confirm: type 99 id 0
debug2: PTY allocation request accepted on channel 0
debug2: channel 0: rcvd adjust 2097152
debug3: receive packet: type 99
debug2: channel_input_status_confirm: type 99 id 0
debug2: shell request accepted on channel 0
Linux PandaCraft 6.1.0-12-amd64 #1 SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Debian 6.1.52-1 (2023-09-07) x86_64

The programs included with the Debian GNU/Linux system are free software;
the exact distribution terms for each program are described in the
individual files in /usr/share/doc/*/copyright.

Debian GNU/Linux comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY, to the extent
permitted by applicable law.
Last login: Fri Sep 22 23:29:00 2023 from 192.168.1.208
```

Comment: Welcome to unix.stackexchange ! The error message is pretty eloquent, but please instead of providing a link to some tutorial: write up the steps you took in your question as concisely as possible.  It'll help in determining where you went astray in configuring your public/private key ssh setup.

Comment: There are 7 lines that say `Trying private key:`, each followed by `No such file or directory`. Your `ssh` has tried 7 default locations for a private key and found no key. Where is your private key then?

Comment: There was a prompt from the `ssh-keygen` command you invoked.  It looked like `Enter file in which to save the key (/home/blaine/.ssh/id_rsa):` .  Did you just press Enter at this prompt, or did you type something?  If you typed something, what did you type?

Answer (score 0):

IDK why but I think it is because I opted in to have Debian install and configure the server as a ssh server I reinstalled Debian on my server and now it works perfectly. I would not consider closing this question as what I did was the nuclear option there must have been some option somewhere that was screwing with the install.

my solution: **NUCLEAR:** do not opt into any of the Debian preconfigured configurations on install. I had to clean install my entire system. Better option yet to be found if you have opted into having Debian preconfigure the ssh server for you.

Comment: Do I get it right? Nuking the old server made your local `ssh` be suddenly able to find your local private key and to log in to the new server that knows nothing about your key? Or did you follow the tutorial again after nuking the server? (and forgot to mention this).

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski I did the same thing I did before which was following the tutorial and it worked perfectly. Only thing I changed was not having Debian configure ssh on install.

Comment: I have not made changed my local config

Comment: Considering the fact your local `ssh` used to be unable to find your private key, I think that following the tutorial again fixed this *local* problem. I'm not saying the server was fine for sure; I'm only noticing the log you posted in the question shows no traces of any remote problem, only this local one. While nuking the server may or may not have been relevant, IMO following the tutorial again was.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski not sure how that would be possible I tried both a id_rsa.pub and a <customname>.pub neither worked before wiping the server.

Comment: I remember having something like this happening on ubuntu server back in the day but can't confirm that however maybe I'll investigate in a vm when I have some free time

Comment: "before wiping the server" – *And* following the tutorial again. My point now is: regardless if nuking the server helped or not, once you did this, informing the new server about your (old or new) key was necessary. Your answer in its current state does not mention following the tutorial again and thus it looks as if nuking *alone* was enough. But I bet it wasn't. If I were you, I would explicitly state in the answer that I followed the tutorial again. I'm not claiming the nuking was pointless, I'm just saying the answer omits important information and can be improved.

Comment: ok bud maybe you could help next time instead of complain about my problem. I forgot to mention that I also attempted to purge and reinstall everything ssh (including the .ssh folder in my home folder) before wiping it this resulted being completely unable to even login to the server over ssh. I have been doing this for years I know when to cut my losses with a nuked environment it would take more time to fix it then to set it up all over again.

Comment: "maybe you could help next time instead of complain" – Well, *this time* I tried. And what? My comment under your question has never been addressed. Four other users agreed the comment was useful, it could lead to a non-nuclear solution. The next comment has never been addressed either. You have the right to remain uncooperative with people who try to help you, sure; but this attitude has consequences. Then my comments under the answer were really to help future users with similar problems. My *impression* is you did not want to help us help you, and now you don't really want to help others.

Comment: I have not marked the my answer as the correct answer however I am guiding users to also not have ssh or other packages being auto configured. later in my current instance I figured that out that ssh does not try every *.pub file (understandably) but a local config (not mentioned in official tutorial) file has to be made. I would have posted different logs (when using id_rsa.pub) with more info however this stack exchange board would not allow it under because of "spam". The other guy was close to helping me find the other half of my problem you however are the problem with the linux community

Comment: This is the last bit before I go you have been sarcastic and unhelpful and it is obvious that you never cared about helping me.